# Get only the name from a dd tag on a website using BS4 and Python, not the entirety of the dd class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract text information from a page and enter it into an excel worksheet. Expected output would be, for example:

Herr Tom Ganskow

But I get the following:

Herr Tom GanskowStraße / HausnummerDriesener Str. 18PLZ / Ort10439 BerlinHandy01792315871Unterkunft Empfehlen Facebook Twitter E-Mail WhatsappLink kopieren

Here's the page in question:
https://mein-monteurzimmer.de/119702/monteurzimmer/berlin-berlin-driesener-str

Here's what I tried (there's more code before this, but this is the bit that's giving me trouble):

```
name = soup.find("dd", itemprop="name")
    if name:
        print(name.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2)
        c1.value = name.text
```

I don't understand why it goes on through all the other tags, if I didn't use find.all?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing parser it may work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://mein-monteurzimmer.de/119702/monteurzimmer/berlin-berlin-driesener-str")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
print(soup.find("dd",attrs={"itemprop":"name"}).text)
```

Output:

```
Herr Tom Ganskow
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to make it work with this change. It also helped me fix some other issues in this program. :) Thanks again.